# How can AWS ELB do session stickiness for mobile clients?

Tags: amazon-web-services, sticky-session

How can AWS ELB do session stickiness for mobile clients? For web clients AWS ELB uses cookies for session stickiness/websockets. But mobile clients typically do not support cookies, then how can this be done?